# c# MDI Parent check child forms opened

Tags: c#, winforms, mdichild, mdiparent

I'm making a MDI windows forms app and I have a panel inside the parent. Everytime I open one child I set the parent's panel visible=false with the event: MdiChildActivate. But when I close all the childs I would like to set the parent's panel to visible=true.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks a lot, maybe is a noob question, but I don't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just subscribe to the Mdi child's `Closed` event and then check if there are any remaining children?

```
void CreateMdiForm()
{
    var child = new SomeMdiChildForm();
    // do stuff
    child.FormClosed += child_Closed;
}

void child_Closed( object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e )
{
    if( MdiChildren.Length == 0 )
    {
        SetPanelVisible();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out [MdiChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.mdichildren.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: @Michael: Ok, so per: *This property allows you to obtain references to all the MDI child forms **currently opened** in an MDI parent form.* it should be `0` then.

Comment: Thanks Ed S. That's what I'm looking for, but I don't understand child.Closed, you means

Comment: @uoah: That is the [FormClosed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) event.  It is fired when the form is, well... closed :)

Comment: Ok thanks, my previous comment doesn't finished, I was asking to you If you means FormCLosed, but now I see you modified your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @uoah: Sorry, `Closed` was deprecated in version 2.0 of .NET.

Comment: No problem :) One question more, I've created child_closed(object sender, FormClosedEventHandler e) but I don't know what to send from child.FormClosed +=child_closed(I_don't_know_to_put_here)

Comment: @uoah: The event expects a an `EventHandler` delegate, in this case, a `FormClosedEventHandler`.  The IDE makes this easy; once you type `+=`, hit TAB twice and it will generate the method for you.  You can omit the `new FormClosedEventHandler(child_Closed)` as the compiler can figure infer it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've tried before but my closed_child args wasn't correct. Thanks again, you helped me a lot :)